# Why is org.w3c.dom parsing my xml wrong?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing

After parsing the following xml,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a>
            <div>
                <span>foo</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

the org.w3c.dom Document parsed with javax.xml.xpath indicates the following:

- `div` is the parent node of `a`
- `a` is the parent node of of `span`

**Why is this, and how can I properly parse this xml?**

Here is the code I am using, followed by the method used to create the Document object, followed by the code's output.

```
String myxml = ""
    + "<html>"
    + "<body>"
    + "<a>"
    + "<div>"
    + "<span>foo</span>"
    + "</div>"
    + "</a>"
    + "</body>"
    + "</html>";

Document doc = HttpDownloadUtilities.getWebpageDocument_fromSource(myxml);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

Node node = ((Node)xPath.compile("//*[text() = 'foo']").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE));

System.out.println("       node tag: " + node.getNodeName());
System.out.println("     parent tag: " + node.getParentNode().getNodeName());
System.out.println("grandparent tag: " + node.getParentNode().getParentNode().getNodeName());

Set<Node> nodes = H.getSet((NodeList)xPath.compile("//*").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET));

for (Node n : nodes) {
    System.out.println();
    try {
        System.out.println("node: " + n.getNodeName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("child: " + n.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

here is the method used to create the Document object:

```
public static Document getWebpageDocument_fromSource(String source) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
        props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(true);
        props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(true);
        props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
        props.setOmitComments(true);

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(source);

        Document doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);

        return doc;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

output:

```
       node tag: span
     parent tag: a
grandparent tag: div

node: html
child: head

node: head

node: body
child: html

node: html
child: body

node: body
child: a

node: a

node: div
child: a

node: a
child: span

node: span
child: #text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the html parser fixes invalid html. Inside a-tags div-tags are not allowed. As soon as you have the Document-object, the html is already parsed, and fixed.

Comment: do you know any good xml cleaners that won't rearrange my nodes?  the default parser works just fine w/ divs inside a-tags: Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(myxml.getBytes()));

Comment: A good html parser/cleaner is JSoup. But as far as I know it also rearranges the structure if it is invalid. If you don't want the structure to be changed you should go with pure xml-parsing.

Comment: If you want this parsed without rearrangement, use an XML parser rather than an HTML parser.

Comment: @MichaelKay & johannesv are there any html cleaners that can be configured to *not* rearrange the structure?  alternatively, are there any pure xml cleaners?  my searches are coming up empty

Comment: Why do you need a cleaner at all? The data you have shown is well-formed XML and doesn't need cleaning.